# What do the numbers mean in antlr4 error and warning messages ?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Can someone point to the antlr 4 documentation or tell me about the numbers in error and warning messages ?

I have a lexer file and a parser file that is generating this warning:

```
warning(125): Sybase\SybTSqlParser.g4:1084:158: implicit definition of token R in parser
```

The numbers "1084:158" do not seem to correspond to a line number or character count.

Comment: Is it not line number + character index of said line? I think it comes from a [ANTLRMessage](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/46b3aa98cc8d8b6908c2cabb64a9587b6b973e6c/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/tool/ANTLRMessage.java), which suggests that. Could you post the grammar? Surely there is a `R` token on line 1084, no?

Comment: Both of us would expect it to be on line 1084. Unfortunately, that is not the case. I think something is screwy when including another .g4 file.

Comment: Can you post the grammar(s)?

Comment: @Bart: Its 5500 lines..  I combined the lexer and parser g4s into a single file. Now the line numbers seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

After some inspiration by Bart Kiers jogging some old memory cells this is the explanation:

When compiling independent lexer and parser files, the lexer files lines are concatenated to the parser file line numbers.

If the lexer has 10 lines and the error is detected on parser file line 25, the error is reported on line 35.